# How to receive multiple request in a Tornado application

Tags: python, asynchronous, tornado

I have a Tornado web application, this app can receive GET and POST request from the client.

The POSTs request put an information received in a Tornado Queue, then I pop this information from the queue and with it I do an operation on the database, this operation can be very slow, it can take several seconds to complete!

In the meantime that this database operation goes on I want to be able to receive other POSTs (that put other information in the queue) and GET. The GET are instead very fast and must return to the client their result immediatly.

The problem is that when I pop from the queue and the slow operation begin the server doesn't accept other requests from the client. How can I resolve this?

This is the semplified code I have written so far (import are omitted for avoid wall of text):

```
# URLs are defined in a config file
application = tornado.web.Application([
    (BASE_URL, Variazioni),
    (ARTICLE_URL, Variazioni),
    (PROMO_URL, Variazioni),
    (GET_FEEDBACK_URL, Feedback)
])

class Server:

    def __init__(self):
        http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(application, decompress_request=True)
        http_server.bind(8889)
        http_server.start(0)

        transactions = TransactionsQueue() #contains the queue and the function with interact with it
        IOLoop.instance().add_callback(transactions.process)

    def start(self):
        try:
            IOLoop.instance().start()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            IOLoop.instance().stop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    server = Server()
    server.start()



class Variazioni(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    ''' Handle the POST request. Put an the data received in the queue '''

    @gen.coroutine
    def post(self):
        TransactionsQueue.put(self.request.body)
        self.set_header("Location", FEEDBACK_URL)


class TransactionsQueue:
    ''' Handle the queue that contains the data
        When a new request arrive, the generated uuid is putted in the queue
        When the data is popped out, it begin the operation on the database
    '''

    queue = Queue(maxsize=3)

    @staticmethod
    def put(request_uuid):
        ''' Insert in the queue the uuid in postgres format '''
        TransactionsQueue.queue.put(request_uuid)


    @gen.coroutine
    def process(self):
        ''' Loop over the queue and load the data in the database '''
        while True:
            # request_uuid is in postgres format
            transaction = yield TransactionsQueue.queue.get()
            try:
                # this is the slow operation on the database
                yield self._load_json_in_db(transaction )
            finally:
                TransactionsQueue.queue.task_done()
```

Moreover I don't understand why if I do 5 POST in a row, it put all five data in the queue though the maximun size is 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to guess that you use a synchronous database driver, so `_load_json_in_db`, although it is a coroutine, is not actually async. Therefore it blocks the entire event loop until the long operation completes. That's why the server doesn't accept more requests until the operation is finished.

Since `_load_json_in_db` blocks the event loop, Tornado can't accept more requests while it's running, so your queue never grows to its max size.

You need two fixes.

First, use an async database driver written specifically for Tornado, or run database operations on threads using Tornado's `ThreadPoolExecutor`.

Once that's done your application will be able to fill the queue, so second, `TransactionsQueue.put` must do:

```
TransactionsQueue.queue.put_nowait(request_uuid)
```

This throws an exception if there are already 3 items in the queue, which I think is what you intend.

Comment: Yes, I'm using psycopg2 for access the database. I'll try to use `ThreadPoolExecutor`, it seems the simplest thing to do now. 
Question: if I use a db driver for tornado (momoko or queries) `_load_json_in_db` must always be a coroutine?

Comment: Correct; any function in a Tornado application that does I/O must be written asynchronously: that is, it must be a coroutine, or it must take a callback that is executed later with the result of the I/O.